# NERR_PasswordTooShort returned when we try to set password. But any information on which complexity is not met?

Tags: c++, security, passwords

When i try to set a password i get NERR_PasswordTooShort error code which according to microsoft is thrown when password policy requirement including the length,age,history requirement and password complexity requirement is not met.

But i wanted to know if there is a way to know which particular requirement is not met( whether length,age,history requirement or password complexity ) as in all this case it throws the generic error NERR_PasswordTooShort

Comment: You can use `NetUserModalsGet` to query the password policy and then work out how it failed to meet the conditions.

Comment: With the above command i can find out what is the password policy set.But how will i find out if that is the parameter because of which it failed. Foe Ex- Suppose the password i used was used before - so the NetUserModalsGet will give me the history requirement like say 24. But i wont know if it was used in previous 24 passwords